# Why is this not loading properly?

Tags: tablesorter

OK, so I've looked at the getting started examples on the documentation available at: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Demo

I am trying the to do the basic example provided in the documentation, however my table does not load with the tablesorter features (i.e. the sort icons on the header, or clickable header columns) as the online version demonstrates. What am I doing wrong?...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Something</title>
        <!-- load tableSorter theme -->
        <link href="http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- load jQuery and tableSorter scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes//jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
        <!-- load tableSorter widgets -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascropt">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("table").tablesorter({
                theme : 'blue',
                widgets : ['zebra','columns'],
                sortList: [[0,0]],
                debug : true,
                widthFixed: false,
                showProcessing : true
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <table class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Due</th>
                    <th>Web Site</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
                    <td>$50.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bach</td>
                    <td>Frank</td>
                    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
                    <td>$50.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
                    <td>$100.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Conway</td>
                    <td>Tim</td>
                    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
                    <td>$50.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the theme option is not being set. When you initialize tablesorter without any options:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter();
```

The "default" theme is set, so make sure to include the "theme.default.css" file; but since it looks like you are loading the "blue" theme stylesheet, initialize the plugin as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascropt">
$(function(){
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({
        theme: "blue"
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, from looking at the blue theme file name, it appears that it might be the original blue theme meant for tablesorter v2.0.5 ("/blue/style.css"). I would venture to guess that the tablesorter being used here is from my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), so make sure to load the file named ["theme.default.css"](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css).

Comment: Mottie! Thanks for pointing out my error. However, this still does not fix things. I have edited my code above for you to peruse. My problem now is that no formatting occurs as if tablesorter hasn't identified the table. I have removed the table "id", FYI. And yes, I am using the fork.

Comment: Well now the plugin is being initialized on `$("mytable")`... it needs a `#` in front to make the selector into an ID or `.` for a class name, neither of which are seen in the HTML.

Comment: No, apologies that was an edit (of the edit) I forgot to change, if you get me. I have now amended it and can confirm it is `$(document).ready(function(){$('table').tablesorter({...` in my actual code. I also have the option `theme : 'blue',` set before other options too. Still nothing.

Comment: Is jQuery being loaded? I see this `src="./includes//jquery-2.1.0.js"` double slashes might be preventing the file from loading... fix that and if it still doesn't work, press F12 and open the console and look for any javascript errors.

Comment: Try fixing this: `<script type="text/javascropt">`... it might be better to just completely remove it: `<script>`

Comment: OK, my bad. So this has fixed the sorting... Though the table still visually has no format; shouldn't the `theme : blue,` have solved this?

Comment: Scrap last question. Solved it by adding the `blue.css` file instead of `default.css`....